# Cannot find App when deploying create-react-app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy my react ao mars-create-react-app buildpack following heroku's own guide for this [Link to relevant Heroku documentation](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration)

However, during running of `git push heroku master`, the script fails during `react-scripts build` with the following error message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/tmp/build_8a984beabf2037d5fc71f69dc6558433/src'
```

Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Locally, the yarn npm build-js command runs without a problem.

The problem seems to be with the import of App.js into index.js, because even tho they are located in the same folder, index.js cannot resolve App.js in none of the three following ways: as `'./App'`, `'./App.js'` and `'App.js'`.

I get the same error with a simple empty create-react-app project so it is not specific to anything I have added in the code.

Comment: Make sure for App path.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please elaborate?

Comment: How? I don't know your folder structure.

Comment: I've checked the path, it is correct.